# open file with default application on iOs

Tags: ios, flash, air

I'm trying to `openWithDefaultApplication` a downloaded file (stored into app documents directory) on iPad. I installed `PDFReaderLite`, still `openWithDefaultApplication` don't rexognizes extension `pdf`. What can I do to make `PDFReaderLite` be a default app for opening pdf?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#openWithDefaultApplication%28%29 This suggests that openWithDefaultApplication is a **desktop** function.  I don't think default application functionality even exists on iOS...

Comment: Yes, I'd read that. There's no prompt that the function does nothing on mobile devices. Any ideas on how to open open file in another way?

Comment: There is only one way to do this on iOS.  You must use a custom URL that the application is designed to open and call the application with it.  However, you cannot add this functionality to existing apps.  It must be added by the author.  This link has more info:  http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"file_1" withExtension:@"pdf"];


    if (URL) {
        // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

        // Configure Document Interaction Controller
        [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

        // Present Open In Menu
        BOOL flag =[self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:[button frame] inView:self.view animated:YES];

        if (!flag) {

             //[appDel showAlert:@"There is no supported app installed in your phone"];
             [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
        }
```